# Geometric Progression Question with terms to infinity

Tags: geometric-progressions

I'm having a problem with the question stated below. I stumbled upon it during my revision And I was hoping one of you guys could help me solve it and better yet Understand how to go about it.

**A geometric Progression has the first term *a*, common ratio *r* and sum to infinity *6*. A second geometric Progression has the first term *2a*, common ratio *r^2* and sum to infinity *7*. What are the values of *a* and *r*

Comment: Do you remember the definition for "geometric progression" -- or "geometric sequence" as some do call it?

Comment: Yes I do remember

Comment: Demonstrate....

Comment: 1,2,3..... (To infinity)

Comment: @RodrigoArts A geometric progression is of form $a,ar,ar^2,...$ your example is an arithmetic progression

Comment: @Vulthuryol Thank you for that. Now That will stick

Comment: The key words "first term" and "common ratio" should remind you in future.

Comment: @Graham Kemp the sure will. I actually asked this question because I've never come across such. I'm a still a first year student and we've not encountered such a question.

Comment: But thank you both very much, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the formula for infinite sums of geometric progressions you obtain the following system of equations:

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{a}{1-r}=6\\ \frac{2a}{1-r^2}=7
\end{cases}$$

According to my calculations, the result is $r=\frac{5}{7}$ and $a=\frac{12}{7}$.

Answer (score 0):

A geometric progression is a sequence of numbers related in *some* manner.    The hints are "first term" and "common ratio".

This sequence has a series, the infinite form of which has a well known closed form.   This is known as the **geometric series**, and if you are revising studies covering this, you should have encountered it in your notes.

> $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha\cdotp \rho^k= \dfrac{\alpha}{1-\rho}\qquad\text{if }\lvert \rho\rvert<1~\vee~\alpha=0$$

Answer (score 0):

so using the formula of sum of infinity...
we will get 2 equation. i) 6 = a/1-r      ii) 7 = 2a/1-r^2

then can do simultaneous equation but i did a much easier way by dividing equation ii) with equation i).....then 'a' will cancel each other and we will get an algebraic expression of 'r'---> r will have 2 values r=5/7 , r=1(ignored coz doesnt make sense XD)
then substitute r to either of the i) or ii) to find a, there you goo. r = 5/7 , a = 12/7 ;D

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).